# LaterJS + useEffect issues a function call multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, laterjs

My code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    later.setInterval(
      async () => {
        console.log('refreshing...', dayjs().format('HH:mm:ss')); // eslint-disable-line 
        const refreshedCredentials = await refreshSession();
        refreshUserSession(refreshedCredentials);
      },
      later.parse.text('every 25 min'),
    );
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line
```

`.setInterval` is supposed to:

> execute (function) for each successive occurrence of the text schedule

In other words, run the function whenever the time matches. However, my function seems to re-run multiple times:

[image]

It's causing unnecessary API requests and I worry it will lag my app later. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

The file in question wraps several react-router Routes (MainLayout):

```
      <MainLayout>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/dashboard"
            component={Dashboard}
          />

          <Route
            exact
            path="/restaurant"
            component={Restaurant}
          />

          <Route
            exact
            path="/reservations"
            component={Reservations}
          />

          <Route
            exact
            path="/dishes"
            component={Dishes}
          />

          <Route
            exact
            path="/dishes/:id"
            component={Dish}
          />
        </MainLayout>
```

Comment: Are there multiple instances of same component? Should also return a function that would stop the interval when component unmounts probably.

Comment: Good question, it's a layout file for several routes. Updated code. The goal is wrap all the protected routes, and use the topmost component to run refreshSession(), specifically to avoid re-renders.

Comment: Assuming that it is only one instance but would see how often useEffect() is getting called to be sure. Never used later.js myself

Comment: I'll try logging outside of the laterjs method.